# Countability of the set

Tags: set-theory, real-numbers

Let $f$ be differentiable function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Consider the set
$$A_y=\{x \in \mathbb{R} : f(x)=y \}$$
I want to know whether $A_y$ is countable for each $y\in \mathbb{R}$. I can verify using simple function like polynomial , exponential function, sine, cosine function; it is countable there. Is it true for any differentiable function?

Comment: Take a constant function ;)

Comment: Can we consider constant function on all $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: what if it is non constant

Comment: Of course you can!

Comment: What is a differential function ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, for the simple reason that constant functions exist.

But there are also nontrivial examples: the function
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
e^{-1/x^2}, &\text{if } x>0, \\ 0, &\text{if } x\le 0
\end{cases}
$$
is differentiable everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x):=y$$ is a differentiable function and $$\{x\in\mathbb R:f(x)=y\}=\mathbb R.$$

You can conclude.

---

For a less trivial example,

$$f(x):=(x+|x|)^2,y=0.$$